# Disappearing function "use" in Sublime Text 3

Tags: php, laravel, sublimetext3

I have a problem with function "use" in Sublime Text 3 (version: 3114).
I am using framework Laravel and when I want edit MY file

> ...\app\Http\Controller\PagesController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function contact(){
        return 'KONTAKT';
    }

        public function about(){
        return 'O NAS';
    }
}
```

And when I click SAVE then disappears me part of the code, and I have this code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class PagesController extends Controller {
    public function contact() {
        return 'KONTAKT';
    }

    public function about() {
        return 'O NAS';
    }
}
```

I don't  have these two lines:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
```

Why this happens? Can somehow fix this ?

P.S I remember that the same thing has happened with Symfony. I had to use a different editor (Notepad++)

This is list my plugin:

1. "CSSLint",
2. "DocBlockr",
3. "Emmet",
4. "FTPSync",
5. "HTML-CSS-JS Prettify",
6. "HTML5",
7. "JavaScript Completions",
8. "jQuery",
9. "JsFormat",
10. "JSHint",
11. "LiveReload",
12. "MySQL Snippets",
13. "Nettuts+ Fetch",
14. "Package Control",
15. "PHP Companion",
16. "PHP Completions Kit",
17. "PHP MySQLi connection",
18. "PHP Zend Framework 2 Helper",
19. "Phpcs",
20. "PhpDoc",
21. "phpfmt",
22. "PhpNamespace",
23. "PHPUnit",
24. "PHPUnit Completions",
25. "Search WordPress Codex or QueryPosts",
26. "SublimeCodeIntel",
27. "SublimeLinter",
28. "SublimeLinter-contrib-bootlint",
29. "SublimeLinter-csslint",
30. "SublimeLinter-html-tidy",
31. "SublimeLinter-jshint",
32. "SublimeLinter-php",
33. "SublimeLinter-phpcs",
34. "SublimeLinter-phplint",
35. "WordPress",
36. "WordPress Developer Resources",
37. "WordpressDev"

Comment: It's probably some plugin that is removing unused `use`s

Comment: @TomKnapen Perhaps, but which of them can cause this an error. This is a list of plugins that I've installed in ST3: [link](http://iv.pl/images/72676865522891529361.png)

Comment: php code beautier , try to disable it

Comment: I removed "php code beautier", the problem still exists

Comment: @major697 please open **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> Package Control -> Settings-User`** and copy the list of installed plugins. Then, using the [edit] functionality on your question, paste and correctly format the list in your question itself. Posting text as an image is **strongly** discouraged - see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1426065) for reasons why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the plugin: phpfmt. Now works correctly;)
Link to phpfmt :[enter link description here](https://github.com/phpfmt/sublime-phpfmt)

Comment: This addon is more of a problem than help. They should add more opt-outs. Until then, I prefer to stay away from it. It just adds a lot of extra work. Especially, when you use Laravel and chain to closure ... you end up with total mess.